# How to delete values from table?

Tags: laravel-5

the below code is controller code.this code works but value is deleted from the page only.From table,the value is not deleted.What can i do to delete value from both page and table??

```
public function deleteconfirms($id)
    {       
         $employee = CreateEmployee::find($id); 

         $employee->destroy($id);           

         Session::flash('flash_notification', array('level' => 'success', 'message' => 'employee deleted successfully'));

         return Redirect::action('Admin\CreateEmployeeController@addemployee');

    }
```

Comment: are you using softdelete ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below code.
In general do not name your model CreateEmployee, call it Employee only. It will create confusion.

```
public function deleteconfirms($id)
{       
     $employee = CreateEmployee::destroy($id); 

     Session::flash('flash_notification', array('level' => 'success', 'message' => 'employee deleted successfully'));

     return redirect()->action('Admin\CreateEmployeeController@addemployee');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When models are soft deleted, they are not actually removed from your database. Instead, a  deleted_at attribute is set on the model and inserted into the database. If a model has a non-null  deleted_at value, the model has been soft deleted.

Check whether you are using  the following code in CreateEmployee model.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class CreateEmployee extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

If you don't want the soft delete, please remove it and use direct delete.